# Concatenate Windows text files with title or date?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, logging, text-manipulation

I have a directory where I have a bunch of text files being dumped for logging that are each in a clean tab delimited format.  Each file is named with it's timestamp which I also need. I need to merge these into one file so I can then offload it to graph and present as statistics.  I can use something like the below command, which works, except I have no timestamps from the files to use in presenting the metrics.

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type “%f” >> output.txt
```

Is there an option that will also write the name of the file above or below that files content, or a way to write into the file a timestamp of when the entry was last modified?

As I mentioned the end product is an Excel spreadsheet getting charts, so if there is a better way to get to this from multiple text files I'd be interested in that as well.

To add context, the text files are formatted log files produced hourly and named with the date/time stamp in numerics with a .txt extension.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there an option that will also write the name of the file?

Use `echo` to also add the filename to the output file.

Here is a example batch file you can modify as appropriate:

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  echo filename: %%f >> output.txt 
  type "%%f" >> output.txt
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The output from `dir` is used otherwise the `.txt` files are processed multiple times.

**Example usage and output:**

```
F:\test\test>dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

12/08/2016  14:04    <DIR>          .
12/08/2016  14:04    <DIR>          ..
11/08/2016  21:07                 8 a.txt
11/08/2016  21:07                 8 b.txt
11/08/2016  21:08                 8 c.txt
               3 File(s)             24 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,769,524,736,000 bytes free

F:\test\test>type *.txt

a.txt


test1

b.txt


test2

c.txt


test3

F:\test\test>..\test

F:\test\test>type output.txt
filename: a.txt
test1
filename: b.txt
test2
filename: c.txt
test3
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [echo](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) - Display messages on screen, turn command-echoing on or off.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `()` to combine multiple commands to a block in order to redirect the output of them to a file, like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if exist output.txt del output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
   echo %%~nf && type "%%f"
) >> output.txt

endlocal
```

I use `&&` to concatenate commands, the brackets are necessary anyway because of the redirection.
The batch addresses several points which @DavidPostill's batch didn't handle:
1- the file "output.txt" would be added to itself if it existed. You can either exclude it from the loop using `IF %%f NEQ output.txt (...)` or just delete it in the beginning.
2- files are sorted by date using `dir /od` which makes the process independent of the format of the filenames - which may or may not be chronologically sorted if sorted alphabetically.
3- to use the filename timestamp as a CSV field, it's extension is removed before writing to the CSV file.

If you need to have the filenames parsed into 2 CSV fields (date and time) then you would have to replace (e.g.) a space with a comma, like in

```
set x=%%~nf && set x=%x: =,% && echo %x% && type "%%f"
```

Similarily if date and time were distinguished by position instead of delimiter.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this one out in the AM at work, but it looks like it better addresses the day/times..